# reading xlsx file using read_xlsx in R with first row as month-year variable

Tags: r, data-import

I have a xlsx data file where the first row is time var given in format (i.e. jan-53 feb-53). I used this command to read the data but R is converting the non-year as number. Following is my command.
`wpi_raw<- read_excel("/Users/sonu/Dropbox/vd_ps/wpi_monthly.xlsx",sheet=1,                       col_names = TRUE,col_types=NULL,na="",skip=0)`
Please suggest how do I go about reading the data with read_excel. I am providing the dropbox link of the data for reference.
`<a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/vpm8hbk63zc1jcd/wpi_monthly.xlsx?dl=0">dpi_monthly</a>`

Comment: Without seeing an example of your data.  I suggest looking up the "as.Date" command.  You should be able convert the inputted string to a date object with something similar to: as.Date(wpi_raw[,1], format = "%b-%y")

Answer (score 2):

When you import dates from excel, you have to convert them from the days since epoch to what you want...

```
library("readxl")
tmp <- tempfile(fileext=".xlsx")
download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/vpm8hbk63zc1jcd/wpi_monthly.xlsx?dl=1",
              destfile=tmp, mode="wb")
wpi_raw <- read_excel(tmp, sheet=1, col_names = TRUE,col_types=NULL,na="",skip=0)

names(wpi_raw)[2:ncol(wpi_raw)] <- format(as.Date(as.numeric(names(wpi_raw)[2:ncol(wpi_raw)]),
                                           origin="1900-01-01"), "%b-%y")
> names(wpi_raw)
 [1] "commodity" "Apr-53"    "May-53"    "Jun-53"    "Jul-53"   
 [6] "Aug-53"    "Sep-53"    "Oct-53"    "Nov-53"    "Dec-53"   
[11] "Jan-54"    "Feb-54"    "Mar-54"
```

Comment: Dear Cory thanks for the help. Could you please explain me the codes also. I tried to understand it but...Further I used following command to reshape the data but now the R is taking month-year var as char `wpi_long <- wpi_raw %>%  gather(month_year,wpi, 2:13,
                              na.rm=FALSE)`. Please suggest as I am putting effor to learn R.

Comment: Yes, the format command takes a numeric date variable and formats it as a string. I think all column names are strings anyways...  To get a date field back takes a little work since the year is only a two digit number. We have to help R out and tell it that it's the 1900s... `wpi_long$date <- as.Date(paste0(gsub("-", "-19", wpi_long$month_year), "_1"), "%b-%Y_%d")`